# What is the fastest classification algorithm for large datasets?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification

What is the fastest classification algorithm?

If I have a very large data set and a very large number of features and I need to conduct classification on it ***within about an hour***.

What would be the fastest classification algorithm?

Comment: I think  Bayesian classifier will be a good one in terms of time. I can't be sure about the accuracy without the actual data

Comment: **1):** What are the `[m-examples,n-features]` dimensions of the `DataSET`? **2):** What are your computing resources capacities available for meeting the set goal **`R [TB]` RAM** `@ fR [MHz]`, in **`H [1]`** computing nodes, having in total **`P [1]` CPU-cores**, running `@ fC [GHz]` CPU-core clock-frequency. **3):** What are your engineering team capacities available `EW [Man-Days]` to fine-tune the processing performance so as to meet your set goal?

Comment: @user3666197 1) Very large dataset and very large nummber of features. 2) I don't know at all about that stuff. 3) I am working alone with no engineering team.

Comment: Yet, what orders of magnitude are you speaking about? **1):** 1E+03, 1E+06, 1E+09 features? 1E+06, 1E+09, 1E+12 examples? **Be specific and quantitative**, it matters, ok?

Comment: Taking the extreme case is what interests me so let's take 1E+09 features and 1E+12 examples.

Comment: Great to finally start with some numbers to touch. Given your DataSET landscape, which has gone to scales above ~ 1E+20++ items, what is your Project financing ( or just another piece of day-dreaming )? If a real Project with financial backing in place and running, would be indeed a great challenge to join such well funded Research group. Congratulations, man. A thrilling endeavour to be in!

Comment: Haha, good one dude. I am interesting in the theoretical case and would like to understand which of the standard classification algorithms (Decision trees, SVMs, Logistic regression, Linear regression, Naive Bayes classifiers) would be the fastest to yield a result ?

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the fastest classification algorithm?

It would depend on the nature of your data, size and dimensions.

Moreover, it would depend on the trade-off you want to achieve between speed and accuracy.

There is no single best algorithm for all cases.

Comment: With all due respect, how do you know the O/P problem is a BigData related before he/she has responded to clarification requests 1) + 2) above? Guessing is not a sign of a responsible problem approach, is it?

Comment: You mean abuot the tag? Yeah I should remove it.

Comment: I understand the trade-off between accuracy and speed, and in the given case I need to focus on speed instead of accuracy. I have very large data and feature sets.

Comment: @Arthurim Arthurim, with all due respect, a focus just on speed results asymptotically in a Dilbert type if predictor. **The ultimately fastest predictor ever is a [CTIME,CSPACE]-Dilbert >>> https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/3d/66/cc3d66aaf378fa9b98d8413be201f64b.jpg.** The **very accuracy is the yardstick**, not a speed ( the more visible in less forgiving domain of regression-type predictions ). Classifiers tolerate sort of doing a lottery draw for a least-wrong result, whereas regressors show you better the naked scale of the truth of the actual inaccuracy and get one sharply warned to care

Comment: Yes, got it.But from the standard models: Decision trees, SVMs, Logistic regression, Linear regression, Naive Bayes classifiers, which one would be the have the best trade-off?